# Display data on screen based on the values selected from the form

Tags: javascript, html, json, angular, typescript

I have to display the data on the screen based on the input received via radio buttons by applying certain conditions. I also need help with fetching the id of an object when the name attribute is selected from the radio button. Here is are the **arrays of objects**

```
  arrayOfObjects = [
    {hiringTypeName : "lateral", hiringTypeId :1,compCode : "IB", compId : 400},
    {hiringTypeName : "new", hiringTypeId :2,compCode : "IB", compId : 401},
    {hiringTypeName : "lateral", hiringTypeId :3,compCode : "BITS", compId : 402},
    {hiringTypeName : "new", hiringTypeId :4,compCode : "BITS", compId : 403},
  ]

  moduleArray =[
    {processName : "offer", processId : 1,data:[{
      name : "demo1", 
      id : 1
    }]},
    {processName : "hire", processId : 2,data:[{
      name : "demo1", 
      id : 1
    }]}
  ]
```

From a different API call i'll get the data from the server which will look like (*for refrence only)

```
  dummyData = [
        {processName : "offer", 
         processId : 1,
         hiringTypeId :1,
         data:[{
            showName : "demo1", showId : 1
    }]},
        {processName : "hire", 
        processId : 2,
        hiringTypeId :1,
        data:[{
            showName : "demo2", showId : 1
    }]},
        {processName : "offer", 
        processId : 2,
        hiringTypeId :3,
        data:[{
            showName : "demo3", showId : 1
    }]},
  ]
```

It will have processName, processId and companyHiringtypeId and each combination of these three will have a array of objects called 'data' associated with it. I want to display the showName in data on he screen based on the selection.

Here is a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hvatox) that I have created with all the basic arrays and form made and **described what I need in the comments in the .ts file.** I have tried to keep the code as clean as I could and to the point. Please ask me for more clarification on the same. Thank You

Comment: You can solve this by writing some code.

Comment: My local machine has all the code but, alas, it dont work.

Comment: MenimE, I suggest you to look the examples in Angular documentation: https://angular.io/start/forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited my answer based on your last comment. In the app.component.ts:

```
  showDummyData() {
    this.selectedDummyData = this.dummyData.filter(a => a.processName === this.selected 
                                                  && a.hiringTypeId === +this.selected1);
  }
```

And in app.component.html:

```
   <div *ngFor="let item of selectedDummyData">
     {{item.data[0].showName}}
   </div>
```

And here the Stackblitz based on your code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fpqbiv

Select the two radio buttons and click "Show Selected Dummy Data".

Comment: I have alerady done that, it shows the correct values. I cannot figure out how to operate on mergeObj to display data

Comment: Then I have to say I don't understand what's your real problem. That piece of code I posted displays the data contained in mergeObj.

Comment: Like I mentioned in the comments (line 83) in .ts file on stackblitz. Thats the requirement